# The case of coincidence of the two tokens using Str::random (or native php method)

Tags: php, laravel

Many developers use Str::random (in Laravel) to generate a random token (no matter what it is used for). In my project, this method is also implemented, and I also have a check for the uniqueness of the api_token field.
There is a small chance that the two tokens may match and an error will occur for the user. Yes, the chance is small, but I want everything to work perfectly : )

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: What kind of "thoughts" are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Both token length has the same value? You can define the value `Str::random(40);` here 40 for 40 characters

Comment: Store every token and look for duplicates, that’s about it. If you have giant values, I guess you could store hashes, instead.

Comment: I usually concat datetime with Str::random, reducing the chances of getting the same token when happens two calls in the exact second

Comment: I've never used larval but looking at the docs, but i'll choose [Str::uuid()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-uuid) if you're really concerned about the low chance of having a non-unique value

Comment: @sta, In my project I use 60 characters for this.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```php
do {
    $token = Str::random(60);
    $data = Model::where('api_token', $token)->get();
}
while ($data->count());

// now the $token is unique
```

You can also mark the database column as `unique()` just so you can have that check on the database level too.

Comment: I don't think that having a unique 60 character column is  recommended. [Read here](https://www.toptal.com/database/database-design-bad-practices) practice 6: _Beware, though, if your table with a composite primary key is expected to have millions of rows, the index controlling the composite key can grow up to a point where CRUD operation performance is very degraded._

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ramsey/uuid** package for Laravel. As the probability that a UUID will be duplicated is not zero, it is close enough to zero to be negligible and how you can read here in it's working methodology.

It works like:

> Collision occurs when the same UUID is generated more than once and assigned to different referents. In the case of standard version-1 and version-2 UUIDs using unique MAC addresses from network cards, collisions can occur only when an implementation varies from the standards, either inadvertently or intentionally.

In contrast to version-1 and version-2 UUID's generated using MAC addresses, with version-1 and -2 UUIDs which use randomly generated node ids, hash-based version-3 and version-5 UUIDs, and random version-4 UUIDs, collisions can occur even without implementation problems, albeit with a probability so small that it can normally be ignored. This probability can be computed precisely based on analysis of the birthday problem

For example, the number of random version-4 UUIDs which need to be generated in order to have a 50% probability of at least one collision is 2.71 quintillion, computed as follows

```
n ≈ 1 2 + 1 4 + 2 × ln ⁡ ( 2 ) × 2 122 ≈ 2.71 × 10 18 . {\displaystyle n\approx {\frac {1}{2}}+{\sqrt {{\frac {1}{4}}+2\times \ln(2)\times 2^{122}}}\approx 2.71\times 10^{18}.} {\displaystyle n\approx {\frac {1}{2}}+{\sqrt {{\frac {1}{4}}+2\times \ln(2)\times 2^{122}}}\approx 2.71\times 10^{18}.}
```

This number is equivalent to generating 1 billion UUIDs per second for about 85 years. A file containing this many UUIDs, at 16 bytes per UUID, would be about 45 exabytes.

The smallest number of version-4 UUIDs which must be generated for the probability of finding a collision to be p is approximated by the formula

```
2 × 2 122 × ln ⁡ 1 1 − p . {\displaystyle {\sqrt {2\times 2^{122}\times \ln {\frac {1}{1-p}}}}.} {\displaystyle {\sqrt {2\times 2^{122}\times \ln {\frac {1}{1-p}}}}.}
```

Thus, the probability to find a duplicate within 103 trillion version-4 UUIDs is one in a billion.

> So if you need more than billion or trillion string then it could
> match one

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer